# ENOTSUP warning

Tags: javascript, git, gruntjs, node-modules

I am using a GitLab. For few part i need the Grunt's CLI.
I have installed Grunt globally by `npm install -g grunt-cli`.

Then I have  install dependencies by `npm install`.

Now, Whenever I am trying to run the Grunt (`$ grunt dev`) I get the following warning.

`ENOTSUP: operation not supported on socket, scandir 'G:\....\buildJs.json' Use --force to continue.
Aborted due to warnings.`

How can i fix this problem?
Any help or suggestion would be very appreciated.